# PHP oci_fetch_array causing out of memory error

Tags: php, oracle, out-of-memory

Im am running a query and retrieving with `OCI_FETCH_ARRAY` and I am getting a fatal error, out of memory after I hit a certain volume of records.  The result array is 100k rows and about 60 columns.
I have my memory_limit in php.ini set to 2 gigs.

```
memory_limit = 2056M
```

It seems to happen when I have more than one person running the script at the same time (or same person running twice as it is set up to run in the background).
It only takes 2 concurrent jobs of 100k records to cause the error.
Everything I've found on OCI_FETCH_ARRAY states that it isn't caching the whole result set in to memory but it looks like it IS.

This is my code (Very straight forward)

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    array_push($resultfile,$row);
    $tablerow=$tablerow +1;
    unset($row);
}
```

The error happens on the OCI_FETCH_ARRAY statement after it hits a certain number of loops.

The output file is only 94m (avg)  so doesn't seem like I should be anywhere memory limit.

Comment: The fact that you're building a giant __in-memory__ array (`$resultfile`) doesn't help.... far better to process each record as you read it rather than storing it in an ever-growing array and then process that array

Comment: Thanks Mark, any idea why it only fails on the oci_fetch_array call and not the array_push?  Secondly, the file is 94mb so why would 3 concurrent instances cause a memory issue if I have memory_limit set to 2gb.

Comment: 100k rows in an array, with 60 columns each.... that's 100k arrays with 6 million values.... and with a typical 48 bytes overhead for each array and for each element you're using 6,100,000 * 48 bytes before you even add the size of the data itself

Answer (score 0):

below code is causing high memory usage :

```
array_push($resultfile,$row);
```

oci_fetch_array is unbuffered meaning it will fetch rows one by one until no rows exists. I would suggest not to push row into another array. instead write your logic inside while loop itself.